# How to multiply answer of a shortcode in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on my wordpress website and I need to multiply answer of a shortcode by 10. Here's the code I am trying -

```
<?php
$first_number = '[affiliates_hits for="month"]';
$second_number = 10;
$sum_total = $second_number * $first_number;
print ($sum_total);
?>
```

I am using a plugin called 'affiliates' and the shortcode [affiliates_hits for="month"] shows the number of visits. Currently when I echo [affiliates_hits for="month"], it shows number 8.

So the above code should result in 80, but it results 0.

Comment: As a wild guess you could try: $first_number = intval('[affiliates_hits for="month"]');

Comment: Not working. It still prints 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a `do_shortcode()`, since you are trying to hard code this in php.

WordPress Codex Resource: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/